# Running Bat file from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code which works:

```
Sub TfrSec()
Dim argh As Double
argh = Shell("C:\Users\Avishen\Desktop\Transfer Rates File.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I want to change Avishen so that it picks up automatically the current user which is login on windows.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Check `Environ("Username")`. I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Isn't there a environ "desktop" also?

Comment: @Andreas no but for the userprovile `Environ("USERPROFILE")` which gives you `C:\Users\Avishen`

Comment: I was probably thinking of specialfolders `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")`

Comment: @Andreas see no benefit in that over using `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"`.

Comment: No there probably isn't. Just that, that is probably what I'm using normally and had it confused with environ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Environ function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/environ-function) to retrieve the environment variables that are set in Windows.

```
Sub TfrSec()
    Dim argh As Double
    argh = Shell(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Transfer Rates File.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

See [here](https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/) for a list of available variables in Windows 10.